# Flutter list return Instance of

Tags: flutter, dart

I get data from json but when try add data to list ant then print list get Instance of

```
class User {
  final String name;

  User(this.name);
}
....................
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = jsonData;
List<dynamic> lst = myMap["items"];
   for(var u in lst ){
       User user = User(u['name']);
       print(u['name']); //return name eg. Marc
       users.add(user);
  }

print(users);  //return Instance of
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override the `toString()` in your `User` class.

Something like this

```
class User {
  final String name;

  User(this.name);

  @override toString() => 'User: $name';
}
```

and then you can use

```
void main() {
  var users = [User("a"), User("b"), User("c")];
  print(users);

  print('----------------');

  for (var user in users) print(user);
}
```